# Hadoop multinode cluster setup - namenode -format returning error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

NOTE: !!!!!!! are next to the relevant part of the output in the code below, where the problem may be (I added that for the purpose of easy finding.)

Below i've attached my output from the result of " hadoop namenode -format". It's possible that this out put could be the result of my reformatting of the namenode as this is the 3rd time I used this command to make it work.

I currently have 5 virtual machine running with the following names:
namenode (this one)
secondaryNamenode,
datanode1,
datanode2,
datanode3.

I was expecting that I could use the namenode web ui on localhost:50070 and see the datanodes using "Live nodes" but I don't see anything there. And help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. The first time I formatted the name node, I seemed to get the right output but despite not seeing any datanodes in the web ui (50070), I thought maybe something was out of place but now the namenode format doesn't seem to work either. The error also mentions that the directory is already locked. (possibly from formatting the namenode a second time, but I could be wrong)

I can provide any more relevant data if needed.

```
[hdadmin@namenode hadoop-1.2.1]$ hadoop 
namenode -format
18/08/06 17:15:53 INFO namenode.NameNode: 
STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = 
namenode.itsid.com/192.168.2.21
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org
/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 
-r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 
15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_181
************************************************************/
Re-format filesystem in /usr/local/hadoop-
1.2.1/tmp/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO util.GSet: Computing 
capacity for map BlocksMap
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO util.GSet: VM 
type       = 64-bit
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max 
memory = 1013645312
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO util.GSet: 
capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO util.GSet: 
recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
18/08/06 17:15:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: 
fsOwner=hdadmin
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: 
supergroup=supergroup
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: 
isPermissionEnabled=true
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: 
dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: 
isAccessTokenEnabled=false 
accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), 
accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
!!!!!!18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.FSEditLog: 
dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.NameNode: 
Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO common.Storage: Cannot  
lock storage /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp
/dfs/name. The directory is already locked.
18/08/06 17:15:56 ERROR namenode.NameNode: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage 
/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp/dfs/name. The 
directory is already locked.
at 

org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$Storag
eDirectory.lock(Storage.java:599)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.form
at(FSImage.java:1338)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.form
at(FSImage.java:1356)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.for
mat(NameNode.java:1261)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.cre
ateNameNode(NameNode.java:1467)
    at 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mai
n(NameNode.java:1488)

18/08/06 17:15:56 INFO namenode.NameNode: 
SHUTDOWN_MSG: 

/**************************************************
**********

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at 
namenode.itsid.com/192.168.2.21

***************************************************
*********/
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Hadoop and Java 7?

Comment: Because I couldn't find an up to date tutorial that works for me... :(

Comment: Is it a big deal?

Comment: Well, Hadoop 3 has been released, and every Hadoop vendor is giving at least Hadoop 2.7...  Java 7 has been end-of-life for years, and Java 8 is reaching that point as well. Plenty of tutorials exist, so it's not clear what you are following other than the **official documentation**. Plus if you want an automated installation, you should look at Apache Ambari (using Hortonworks or Apache BigTop repo)

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks for that info then, could you by any chance recommend either where to find the official documentation for installing hadoop or a guide(video or written) for using Apache Ambari using those other addons to automatically install it? Thanks again!

Comment: Again, the official documentation from the various apache.org sites is a fine place to start. Otherwise, docs.hortonworks.com. If you want to use VMs, search Github for "vagrant hadoop", and you'll probably get plenty of hits, then just learn a little bit about Vagrant

Comment: Thank you so much cricket_007! You rock!